# update field when max(BCASTdate -120)<= date

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a sql table where i need to update MIGRATE field to "M" when BC_DATE MINUS 120 days is less than equal to derived date 
this should be my output

```
 BC_DATE        Migrate Flag
 2018-09-09       M
 2018-11-01       M
 2018-12-21       M
 2019-01-13      NULL
 2019-02-13      NULL
 2019-03-13      NULL

 declare @date int null
 set @date = '20190401'

 update table 
 set Migrate_flag = 'M'
 when max(convert(varchar,dateadd(day,-120,[BCAST DATE]),112)) < = @date
```

please correct my update statement to work.

Comment: What's the data type of `[BCAST DATE]`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want:

```
 update table 
     set Migrate_flag = 'M'
     where [BCAST DATE] < dateadd(day, -120, convert(date, convert(varchar(255), @date)));
```

There is no reason to be converting the dates to strings for this comparison.

But why would you have `@date` be an `int`?  You should just declare it as a `date`:

```
declare @date date;
set @date = '20190401'
```

Comment: Here is the error i got:
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 27
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
The statement has been terminated.

BCAST DATE is in this format 2019-03-01
date is in this format 20190301